# use enum or dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a database with an status field that can keep the following values:

- 0 Registrado
- 1 Activo
- 2 Finalizado
- 3 Anticipado
- 4 Reestructurado

Of course I just keep the number in a tinyint datatype in my database. Then I need to query that table but the GUI must show string value and not numeric value.

What is the best way to achieve it? Should I use a Enum datatype or dictionary ? What would the advantages of using one over the other?

In addition, results will be shown in a datagrid

Comment: Dictionary<int,string> looks an awful lot like string[] semantics for now...

Comment: if using entity framework I would use an entity, no enum and no dictionary. so that if there is a new entry in that table you do not need to rebuild anything...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @DavidePiras in fact i'm using the entity framework, could you explain me a little bit how the entity would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I would take is

- Map the `tinyint` values into an `enum`
- Create a static `Dictionary<TheEnumType, string>` which maps the values to the user string

For example

```
public enum Names {
  Registrado = 0,
  Activo = 1,
  Finalizado = 2,
  Anticipado = 3,
  Reestructurado = 4
}
```

Now you can easily convert between the DB value and the appropriate enum

```
int theDbValue = ...;
Names name = (Names)theDbValue;
```

Building up the mapping between the names can now be easily done with a `Dictionary<Names, string>`.

```
var map = new Dictionary<Names, string>();
map[Names.Registrado] = "...";
map[Names.Activo] = "...";
// etc ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking about a limited amount of choices i would suggest enums since performance wise they are a lot better. A couple of similar questions that could help

- [c# enum and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256713/c-sharp-enum-and-performance)
- [Which is faster/more efficient: Dictionary or Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820200/which-is-faster-more-efficient-dictionarystring-object-or-dictionaryenum-obj)